# GROUP_CONCAT() eqivalent in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

In MySQL I use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, nevertheless now i need to convert that to Postgres. Can anyone help me out how to convert such query into Postgres? I think the only one which has to be replaced is the line with `GROUP_CONCAT`?

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT CONCAT(
   'SELECT ',GROUP_CONCAT(c.TABLE_NAME,'.',c.COLUMN_NAME,' AS `',c.TABLE_NAME,'.',c.COLUMN_NAME,'`'),'
    from t1 AS thre
inner join t2 as ter on thre.datasource = ter.datasource 
inner join t3 as ston on thre.datasource = ston.datasource
inner join t4 as diron on thre.datasource = diron.datasource'
)
INTO @sql
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME IN ('t1','t2',
                       't3','t4');    
PREPARE sql_statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE sql_statement;
```

Comment: And many more answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=Relevance&q=%5bpostgresql%5d%20group_concat) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+string-aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `STRING_AGG`

```
select 'SELECT '||string_agg(c.TABLE_NAME||'.'||c.COLUMN_NAME||' AS '
                           ||c.TABLE_NAME||'.'||c.COLUMN_NAME ,',') ||
            'from t1 AS thre inner join t2 ..
            ..
            .. = diron.datasource'              
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
```

`||` is the concatenation operator in Postgres

Comment: hmm that doesnt work i get in result one column with value

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `string_agg()` function

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html